# Scala: why duplicate declaration is allowed inside pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

It seems that we are able to bind pattern to identifier `x` and then to declare one more `x` identifier immediately in the same scope. Why does this code work?

```
"123" match {
  case x@"123" =>
    // I expected compilation error here, but it actually works. Even var works
    val x = "456"
    x // "456"
}
```

Explaining with something like link to SLS would be especially appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it just the scoping, as in `def f(x: Int) = { val x = 0 }`?

Comment: You surely get a compiler warning out of this declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a dedicated explanation of this situation in SLS, but looking at [Pattern matching expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions) part of spec, one can find the following wording:

> A pattern matching expression
>
> ```
> e match { case p_1 => b_1 … case p_n => b_n }
> ```
>
> The scope of the pattern variables in p_i comprises the pattern's guard
>   and the corresponding block b_i.

Which can be understood as the block `b_i` has its own scope, which is nested into the scope of pattern variables.

Now your variable `x` is bound in the pattern variable scope `p_i`, and then is redefined in the `b_i` scope. This gives us the situation of nested scopes, and the normal rules of name shadowing in the nested scope apply.